# Mobile Safari fails to create SQLite DB

Tags: ios, sqlite, safari

I have a strange bug on my iPhone's Safari.
A service located at the http://i.zenmoney.ru tries and fails to create a database in my Safari. But if I use another iPhone (with the same iOS 5.0.1) or use another browser (like Atomic) everything works correctly.

I tried clearing all Safari's data via settings but nothing helps.

I use iPhone 4 with iOS 5.0.1

Comment: Have you tried a restore? That usually fixes these types of problems.

Comment: Do you mean full phone restore via iTunes?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the Safari settings and confirmed that you are not using private browsing?
I recently had the same problem on my iPad and the error was "Not Authorized". It turned out that I had turned on private browsing. When I turned it off the problem went away.